# IIS URL Rewrite rule required for Query parameter set with semicolon

Tags: jakarta-ee, url-rewriting, coldfusion

I have an application (coldfusion) running on IIS which uses J2EE session variables.
Unfortunately the jsessionid query parameter is appended to the URL in the following format

`https://wesiteurl/public/home;jsessionid=xxx?parm1=yyy&parm2=zzz`

Although semicolon is a valid separator, the internal part of the application writing `parm1` & `parm2` does not cater for it (nor does IIS).

Is is possible to have an IIS rewrite rule which converts the `';jsessionid=xxx'` to either `'?jsessionid=xxx'` or `'&jsessionid=xxx'` and append it to the end

Comment: Why are you passing the jsessionid in the URL? That is a security risk and not necessary. It should be passed as a cookie instead.

Comment: The application I'm using is Coldfusion.  It also needs to work when cookies are not accepted; hence query string

Comment: I see you want to stick on Coldfusion with session IDs in the URL, but as @Miguel-F already commented, this is as of 2021 a security risk and should be avoided, on Coldfusion or any other web application. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161198/what-exactly-are-the-security-concerns-with-sending-session-tokens-in-the-url

Comment: @pked How old is this application? Is there any legit current reason to not allow cookies? Odds are, this isn't the only security update that needs to be addressed. https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Session_hijacking_attack